# javascript bind function is not being trigger on first action

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi i have the following code in which i bind a function to ladda ( the ladda library). Everything works except the first onsubmit. For the function to be trigger the first time I need to press the submit button twice. I figure it has something to do with not being bound during initialization.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function test(){
        Ladda.bind( '#submitPatientAcquisition',{
                        callback: function( instance ){
                            console.log("start progress button")
                            $('#patientsLostTable').DataTable().clear().draw()

                            var progress = 0;
                            var completed = false
                            getPatients(yrfrom, yrto).then(function(results){
                                $('#patientsLostTable').DataTable().clear().draw()
                                $('#patientsLostTable').DataTable().rows.add(results["data"]).draw();
                                completed = true
                            }).catch(function(err){
                                console.log(err)
                            })
                            var interval = setInterval( function(){
                                progress = Math.min( progress + Math.random() * 0.05, 1 );
                                instance.setProgress( progress );

                                if( completed ){
                                    instance.stop();
                                    clearInterval(interval);
                                }
                            }, 200 );


                     }
                    }); }

});
```

Comment: Hard to tell based on what you have posted, but you may need to ensure the document is loaded first: `$(document).ready(function(){ // code });`

Comment: it is in document ready

Comment: are you sure the bind should take a callback function as you have it? You are supplying an object with a property called "callback" rather than an actual function - is that ok?

Answer (score 0):

the binding needs to occur within the scope of document ready not within a function. the function is not trigger until called - so either i needed to call the function in document ready, or bind outside of a function